# Fetch API - data values

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect

The following code works where the data from fetch is being rendered but when I try to save the value of a fetched field in a variable, its giving error:

```
    //get data api - Global data
    const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState();
    const [dataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchGlobalData() {
            setDataLoading(true)
            const url = "https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats";
            const apiResponse = await fetch(url)
            console.log(apiResponse)
            const dataFromAPI = await apiResponse.json()
            console.log(dataFromAPI)
            setGlobalData(dataFromAPI)
            setDataLoading(false);
        }
        fetchGlobalData()
    }, [])
    
    if (dataLoading) {
        return (
            <div> ... Loading Data .. </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <Paper elevation={6}>
              <div className={classTypography.root}>
                <Typography
                  variant="h4"
                  gutterBottom
                  style={{ color: "blue", fontWeight: "bold" }}
                >
                  <NumberFormat
                    value={
                      globalData &&
                      globalData.results &&
                      globalData.results[0].total_cases
                    }
                    displayType={"text"}
                    thousandSeparator={true}
                    renderText={(value) => <div>{value}</div>}
                  />
```

BUT: Error in this code, trying to save the value of the fetched (same fetch) field to a var:

```
  //get data api - Global data
  const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState();
  const [dataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchGlobalData() {
      setDataLoading(true);
      const url = "https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats";
      const apiResponse = await fetch(url);
      console.log(apiResponse);
      const dataFromAPI = await apiResponse.json();
      console.log(dataFromAPI);
      setGlobalData(dataFromAPI);
      setDataLoading(false);
    }
    fetchGlobalData();
  }, []);

    if (dataLoading) {
        return <div> ... Loading Data .. </div>;
    } else {
        
        tot_kases =  {
          globalData &&
                globalData.results &&
                globalData.results[0].total_cases`
        }
```

./src/components/GlobalD2.jsx
Line 52:22:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

```
  50 |         
  51 |         tot_kases =  {
> 52 |           globalData &&
     |                      ^
  53 |                 globalData.results &&
  54 |                 globalData.results[0].total_cases`
  55 |         }
```

I tried the following and got compile errors:

```
tot_kases =  {globalData.results[0].total_cases}
```

Line 51:33:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

```
Its not clear here but it does not like '.' after globalData:
  49 |     } else {
  50 |         
> 51 |         tot_kases =  {globalData.results[0].total_cases}
```

I am new to REACT so please feel free to guide me as to how to do it better n more efficiently.

Comment: Try changing it to `tot_kases =  {total_cases : globalData.results[0].total_cases}`

Comment: to add: here is the error when i omit && ..:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
GlobalData
C:/Nusrat/react/covid19/src/components/GlobalD2.jsx:51
  48 |     return <div> ... Loading Data .. </div>;
  49 | } else {
  50 |     
> 51 |     const tot_kases =  (globalData.results[0].total_cases)
     | ^  52 |

Comment: Nitish: same error when i try our suggestion: 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
let tot_cases;
const total_cases = globalData && globalData.results.length && globalData.results[0].total_cases;
if(total_cases) {
    tot_cases = {...total_cases}
}
```

You can make use of the optional chaining operator if you have added it to you have access to it by simply replacing

```
globalData && globalData.results.length && globalData.results[0].total_cases
```

with `globalData?.results?.[0]?.total_cases`

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
GlobalData
C:/Nusrat/react/covid19/src/components/GlobalD2.jsx:59
```
  56 | if (total_kases) {
  57 |   tot_kases = { ...total_kases };
  58 | }
> 59 |         const tot_unr_kases =
  60 |                 (globalData.results[0].total_active_cases +
  61 |                     globalData.results[0].total_unresolved)
  62 |     
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
GlobalData
C:/Nusrat/react/covid19/src/components/GlobalD2.jsx:61
 ```
 58 | // }
  59 |    
  60 |         const tot_kases =  (globalData?.results?.[0]?.total_cases);
```

Comment: I am not sure about how you get that error because the first check is globalData and the execution stops there if the globalData is undefined.

Comment: Harsha: What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for assigning `total_cases` only if `globalData.result[0]` is avaialble.

```
tot_kases = {
  ...(globalData?.results?.[0] && {
    total_cases: globalData.results[0].total_cases,
  }),
}
```

```js
let globalData;

//This will lead to compilation error.
//This is not a valid syntax, since the json object which is being assigned is not a valid one as key is missing.
let tot_kases = {
  globalData && globalData.results && globalData.results[0].total_cases
}
```

Below is the example simulating different scenarios.
You can assign the value by either of these following approaches

```js
let globalData;

let tot_kases = globalData?.results?.[0].total_cases

//globalData is undefined
console.log(tot_kases)

globalData = { results: null}

tot_kases = globalData?.results?.[0].total_cases
//globalData.results is null
console.log(tot_kases)

globalData = { results: [{total_cases:100}]}

tot_kases = globalData?.results?.[0].total_cases
console.log(tot_kases)
```

```js
let globalData;

let tot_kases = {
  ...(globalData?.results?.[0] && {
    total_cases: globalData.results[0].total_cases,
  }),
}

//globalData is undefined
console.log(tot_kases)

globalData = { results: null}

tot_kases = {
  ...(globalData?.results?.[0] && {
    total_cases: globalData.results[0].total_cases,
  }),
}
//globalData.results is null
console.log(tot_kases)

globalData = { results: [{total_cases:100}]}

tot_kases = {
  ...(globalData?.results?.[0] && {
    total_cases: globalData.results[0].total_cases,
  }),
}
console.log(tot_kases)
```

Change your component to like below

```
  const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState();
  const [dataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchGlobalData() {
    //...your code as is 
    if (dataLoading) {
        return <div> ... Loading Data .. </div>;
    } else {
        // if you want your `tot_kases` to hold the value
        tot_kases = globalData?.results?.[0].total_cases
        //or like below if `tot_kases` to hold the object
        //tot_kases = {...(globalData?.results?.[0] && {total_cases:globalData.results[0].total_cases,}),
}
//rest of your code.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/components/GlobalD2.jsx
  Line 63:35:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  61 |     //const tot_kases = { globalData && globalData.results.length && globalData.results[0].total_cases};
  62 |         
> 63 |     const tot_kases = { globalData.results[0].total_cases }
     |                                   ^
  64 |
does not like the . after globalData in line 63 ..

Comment: What baffles me is that a vlaue is rendered fine in components, but can not save  it?  Please compare the code posted in the initial question

Comment: The problem in assigning like this is `{ globalData && globalData.results && globalData.results[0].total_cases }` that you are trying to assign the value if `globalData` and `globalData.results` are available. But this is not a valid syntax as the `key` is missing in the json object which you are trying to assign to `tot_kases`

Comment: To clarify, this is the code:
  tot_kases =  {
          globalData &&
                globalData.results &&
                globalData.results[0].total_cases
        }
I am trying to save ' globalData.results[0].total_cases' as 'tot_kases'.

Comment: Yes I understood that, but the way you are trying to assign is not a valid syntax. I have updated my answer simulating the scenarios and the way you want to assign/save.

Comment: Hi Nitish, thanks for taking the time to suggest a solution. It escapes my understanding though. Please see my original posted code in the question above. Bottom half of the code works fine .. return (...... total_cases are displayed fine, but i am not able to save the values. 
 why would that be?

Comment: That is what, it's working in `return (.....` in first code for displaying because the value is being sent as prop rather than the JSON object but where as when you are trying to save you are using to save as `json object` so either change it to `tot_kases = globalData && globalData.results && globalData.results[0].total_cases` or refer the solution I posted.